# How to get checkboxes from FormCollection?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using asp.net MVC.

I have strong type view (List) of some table e.g. Index method

now I put **four** checkboxes for each row,

Like [alt text http://img411.imageshack.us/img411/7140/24296349.png](http://img411.imageshack.us/img411/7140/24296349.png)

Now I submit the form.

In controller there is method called

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Index(FormCollection result)
```

Question : What would be the name and id property of each check box, so that I can easily manipulate them?

Let's say if I get 2D array of check boxes then it is easy to store options for each record.

Comment: How to get checkboxes from formCollection isn't a question, it is a statement.

Comment: How are you generating that table? Is it custom HTML, or some canned grid?

Comment: That table isn't having above check boxes. I'm putting them by writing HTML code. And to store them, I use another table.

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't particularly clear but from my understanding you wish to retrieve the values associated with the check boxes from the form collection and pass these values into th controller.

```
int[] checkboxIndecies=new int[] { /* checkbox indecies*/ }
bool[] checkboxValues=new bool[checkboxIndecies.Length];

for (int i=0; i < index_of_last_checkbox.Length; i++)
{
checkboxValues[i]=Convert.ToBoolean(FormsCollection[checkboxIndecies]);

}
```

That should get the value of each of the checkboxes from the forms collection, convert them to bool and place them im checkboxValues

Appolagises if this is unclear or just plain bad code, feel free to correct me

Comment: I've updated question. please check it, and I don't want to pass formcolletion values into ohter controller. I just want to get it from the form only. The form is nothing but an Index view of model entity.